# ODE45 which i can not solve

Tags: matlab, ode45

I have a problem to use ODE45. I gave the matlab code below. I can not start the solver. Probably it is a syntax error. If you can find the problem i would be happy.

It is a modeling and simulation of packed bed reactor. However; i get errors before starting the real simulation :)

```
clear all % Clear workspace and variables %
close all % Close all figures %
clc       % Clear command window for fresh start %

temp_array=[500;550;600;650;700;750;800;850];
pressure=1;
reactor_h=60;
reactor_d=10;
bed_dens=1500;
P_EtOH_0=0.5;
P_CO2_0=0.5;
space_t=24.89;

reactor_volume = pi * ((reactor_d/2)^2) * reactor_h; % Reactor volume in mm3 %
reactor_volume_m3 = reactor_volume * 10^(-9); % Reactor volume in m3 %

m_cat=reactor_volume_m3*bed_dens;
m_cat=0.002; %kg

F_EtOH_0=m_cat/space_t; %kmol/h
F_CO2_0=F_EtOH_0*P_CO2_0/P_EtOH_0; % kmol/h

for i=1:1

temp=temp_array(i);

[V,X]=ode45(@(V,X)RateFuncTempEffect(V,X,temp,F_EtOH_0,F_CO2_0,pressure,m_cat,reactor_volume_m3), [0 reactor_volume_m3], 0);

end

function fnc = RateFuncTempEffect(V,X,temp,F_EtOH_0,F_CO2_0,pressure,m_cat,reactor_volume_m3)

freq_factor = 6.78*10^5; % kmol/kg cat h (atm)^4.91 %
activ_energy = 97.87; % kJ/mol %
R_kJ = 8.3144598; % kJ/mol K %

F_EtOH = (1-X)*F_EtOH_0;
EtOH_reacted = F_EtOH_0 - F_EtOH;
F_CO2 = F_CO2_0 - EtOH_reacted;
F_CO = 3*EtOH_reacted;
F_H2 = 3*EtOH_reacted;

F_total = F_EtOH + F_CO2 + F_CO + F_H2;

frac_EtOH = F_EtOH/F_total;
frac_CO2 = F_CO2/F_total;
%frac_CO = F_CO/F_total;
%frac_H2 = F_H2/F_total;

P_EtOH = frac_EtOH * pressure;
P_CO2 = frac_CO2 * pressure;

k = freq_factor*exp(activ_energy/(R_kJ*temp)); % Rate constant %
rA = -k * (P_EtOH)^0.96 * (P_CO2)^3.95; % Rate expression %

cat_dens=m_cat/reactor_volume_m3;

fnc = (-rA/flow_EtOH0)/cat_dens;
end
```

Comment: You put your subfunction in a script ? Matlab is not going to accept such a thing.

Comment: If there is a "syntax error"  the when you try the code, MATLAB will tell you "syntax error". Does it?

Comment: I can put my subfunction in a script in another simpler one and it works.

Comment: I don't know whaether  it is syntax error or not. But i can not run this script.

Comment: @hksdejavu You can not run this script because function declarations are not allowed in scripts. Im 100% sure that MATLAB is telling you that

Comment: What are these "syntax errors" that you are getting ?

Comment: @AnderBiguri: It's valid in Matlab R2016b+. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html).

Comment: @horchler the more you know. Thanks for the informationn